# Providing a higher voltage to a motor

Tags: motor

I have a 9v motor but I want to give it a lot of voltage so that it can open a door lock so if I attach it to a 18 v battery source will it be alright?

Noob in electronics . Help is highly appreciated

Comment: It will be fine up until the point the windings melt.

Comment: @Majenko ur comment seems satirical pls help. Will it work , I will only have it work for like five seconds

Comment: It *might* work once for 5 seconds or so ... will it work a second time? Maybe not...

Comment: What does this have to do with over*clocking*?

Comment: Instead of asking us if 18V will damage your (undisclosed) motor, why not share what type/part number motor you're using, and what kind of force you're trying to get out of it. Then we can actually help you with how to make it work.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out for yourself?

Comment: you could probably get away with a PWM driven low-side motor circuit, and with a 50% duty cycle you will be putting an average of 9V across it instead of 18V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definative answer is in the datasheet.  See what it says about short term over-voltage.

The limitations on the voltage you are allowed to apply to a motor include:

Arcing between conductive parts that are physically close.

Insulation breakdown.

Excessive current.  This causes damage because of the heat due to higher than intended current thru the resistive component of the windings.  The heat can damage lubrication, run bearings out of tolerance, or outright melt something.

Points 1 and 2 aren't a issue at your relatively low voltages, but point 3 is a serious issue.  The heat the motor has to dissipate goes with the square of the current thru it, so all else being equal, going from 9 V to 18 V will at least *quadruple* the heat produced internally.  That means the internal parts will heat up "quickly", but you don't know how long it will take to get to damaging levels.

For a short time, the over-voltage will be OK.  The temperature will go up more quickly than usual, but if you stop before it gets to the design temperature, things will be OK.  The problem is you don't know how short a time that is unless the datasheet tells you how long you can over-voltage the motor for.  A few milliseconds is *probably* fine, *probably* even a few 10s of ms.  A few 100 ms may be OK, but you don't know.  A few seconds could easily be not OK.

Another thing to consider is that at a fixed motor speed, the current goes up faster than the square of the voltage.  The voltage across the coils is the applied voltage minus the back EMF created by the motor acting as a generator.  That back EMF is directly propotional to the motor speed.  For example, if the motor is being driven from 9 V and is running at a speed that produces 3 V back EMF, then the windings are really "seeing" 6 V.  If you raise the driving voltage to 18 V and the motor stays at the same speed, then the windings will see 15 V, which is 2.5 times what they saw at 9 V, and will cause over 6 times more heat.

The correct answer is to get the right motor for the job, and then drive it according to its specifications.

Comment: Not wat I was hoping for but thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that opening a door lock requires more torque, not more speed. If your motor simply stalls at 9V, you definitely need more torque. That means you need to supply more current to the motor.

If your 9V supply is one of those little rectangular batteries, it simply can't supply very much current, and using 2 in series won't help very much - just flatten 2 batteries quickly. Measure the actual voltage across the motor - if it's much less than 9V, that's the problem.

To generate more torque from the same motor and battery, add gearing to reduce speed and increase torque.